# How to filter all values in Bash's regular expression (Linux) except one?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a csv file with the following head:

```
Unnamed: 0;Unnamed: 0.1;year;country;word;frequency;count;freq_prop_headlines;word_len;freq_rank;hfreq_rank;theme
```

And I have to filter the results between the years 2010 and 2011.

I created an sh:

```
grep -E '^([^;]*;){2}(2010|2011);' $1
```

Now, I have to improve the previous regular expression selecting all the countries in the column "country" except the value "all countries". And I did:

```
grep -E '^([^;]*;){2}(2010|2011);^all countries.*;' $1
```

But it didn't work.

Shall you help me, please?

Thank you!!!

Edit:

Sample data:

```
Unnamed: 0;Unnamed: 0.1;year;country;word;frequency;count;freq_prop_headlines;word_len;freq_rank;hfreq_rank;theme
10450;61006;2020;all countries;relationship;603;381402;0.001581009;12;656;653;female stereotypes
10451;61007;2021;all countries;relationship;270;234227;0.001152728;12;656;653;female stereotypes
10452;61013;2010;all countries;burn;36;35448;0.001015572;4;657;657;crime and violence
10453;61014;2011;all countries;burn;75;58436;0.001283455;4;657;657;crime and violence
10454;61015;2012;all countries;burn;105;94038;0.00111657;4;657;657;crime and violence
8928;51085;2010;USA;gangrape;0;1912;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
8929;51086;2011;USA;gangrape;0;3274;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
```

And the output must be the following:

```
8928;51085;2010;USA;gangrape;0;1912;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
8929;51086;2011;USA;gangrape;0;3274;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
```

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output by editing your question

Comment: With PCRE regex: `grep -P '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];(?!all countries).*;' $1`

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @anubhava edited with the sample data and the output!

Comment: grep isn't bash's built-in regex support -- it's a completely separate tool, not part of bash at all. bash's regex facility is `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`. (Also, be mindful that sh and bash are two different languages; if what you mean when you say you "created a sh" is that you built a `#!/bin/sh` script instead of a `#!/bin/bash` script, then you aren't using bash and can't use bash-specific features like the above-referenced built-in regular expressions).

Comment: (btw, `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` _does_ use ERE syntax; if you were told that you must use `grep -E`, say that explicitly instead of saying that you just need to use ERE in general, since there are lots of tools that support ERE, beyond just grep).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I translated the statement:

Extend the above regular expression to get a single
ERE type expression that returns the records:
- that are from the year 2010 or 2011,
- and that the value of the country column is not "all countries"

Comment: Hmm. Honestly, I tend to agree that it's a bad choice of tools for the job, and thus a poorly designed assignment that's forcing you to use practices that would be frowned on if used in the real world.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand your point of view, but I am pursuing a Master Degree in Data Science and in the subject of Scripting I got this statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` is more suitable for this job more as input is `;` separated column row data.

```bash
awk -F ';' '$3 ~ /^201[01]$/ && $4 != "all countries"' file

8928;51085;2010;USA;gangrape;0;1912;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
8929;51086;2011;USA;gangrape;0;3274;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
```

As OP is looking for only a solution involving `grep -E` here is a solution doing that:

```bash
grep -E '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];([^a]|a[^l]|al[^l]|all[^ ]|all [^c]|all c[^o]|all co[^u]|all cou[^n]|all coun[^t]|all count[^r]]|all countr[^i]]|all countri[^e]|all countrie[^s])' file

8928;51085;2010;USA;gangrape;0;1912;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
8929;51086;2011;USA;gangrape;0;3274;0.0;8;856;856;crime and violence
```

Comment: My trouble is I am doing a Master's Degree task and it's mandatory to use an ERE expression.

Comment: If I use:

grep -E '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];all countries;' file

I will filter the value "all countries" and I need to select all the values except "all countries".

Comment: I am sorry! Edited the OP again!

Comment: I don't doubt that awk is more suitable, but using grep -E is mandatory for this exercise. I know it is a mess...

Comment: So you cannot use `grep -P '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];(?!all countries;)' file` ?

Comment: @anubhava, ...the OP has said that already, after Wiktor provided a `grep -P` solution in a comment on the question

Comment: As I said to Charles Duffy, the statement is:

Extend the above regular expression to get a single
ERE type expression that returns the records:
- that are from the year 2010 or 2011,
- and that the value of the country column is not "all countries"

Comment: ok I have provided a solution using `grep -E`

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditions on 3rd field in case your range of comparison of numbers is wide, try following `awk` code then. Simple explanation would be, making field separator as `;` and checking condition if 3rd field is equal to 2010 OR 2011 AND 4th field is NOT equal to `all countries` then print that line.

```
awk -F';' '($3==2010 || $3==2011) && $4 != "all countries"' Input_file
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but using grep -E is mandatory :(