# How to end up this regex in ERE

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am pursuing the subject of Scripting in my Master Degree of Data Science and I did the previous question below:

[How to filter all values in Bash's regular expression (Linux) except one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183424/how-to-filter-all-values-in-bashs-regular-expression-linux-except-one)

I learned that ERE is not exactly Bash. But I am stuck again.

Traducing the statement of the assingment:

The regular expression must be used within a Bash script called
script.sh that runs a grep command. The script should work
running as follows:

./script.sh ./headlines_words.csv

The sample data of the file headline_words.csv is:

```
Unnamed: 0;Unnamed: 0.1;year;country;word;frequency;count;freq_prop_headlines;word_len;freq_rank;hfreq_rank;theme
14;279;2012;India;cricketer;0;3634;0.0;9;20;20;empowerment
8964;52224;2010;USA;witchcraft;0;1912;0.0;10;935;935;female stereotypes
9887;57556;2021;all countries;hate;312;234227;0.001332041;4;436;429;crime and violence
```

And I have three conditions to achieve:

- The years are from 2010 to 2011
- The value of the freq_rank column is greater than or equal to 910
- The country column is not "all countries"

So, the correct output of ./script.sh ./headlines_words.csv must be:

```
Unnamed: 0;Unnamed: 0.1;year;country;word;frequency;count;freq_prop_headlines;word_len;freq_rank;hfreq_rank;theme
8964;52224;2010;USA;witchcraft;0;1912;0.0;10;935;935;female stereotypes
```

I used grep -E (I know it is not suitable but is mandatory to use it) with the following code for script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -E '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];([^a]|a[^l]|al[^l]|all[^ ]|all [^c]|all c[^o]|all co[^u]|all cou[^n]|all coun[^t]|all count[^r]]|all countr[^i]]|all countri[^e]|all countrie[^s]);[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;9[1-9][0-9]{2,}' $1
```

The part of:

```
^([^;]*;){2}201[01];
```

And:

```
([^a]|a[^l]|al[^l]|all[^ ]|all [^c]|all c[^o]|all co[^u]|all cou[^n]|all coun[^t]|all count[^r]]|all countr[^i]]|all countri[^e]|all countrie[^s])
```

Worked separately and together.

But the last part:

```
[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;9[1-9][0-9]{2,}'
```

I have an error because when I run the code ./script.sh ./headlines_words.csv in Ubuntu the terminal doesn't give me any row.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Learning to parse CSV (not really CSV, separated by `;`) is not the better use case to learn regex :/

Comment: Which error? You said you have an error, but don't explain which one

Comment: It looks like you have some sort of CSV; why do you want to process it with `grep` and incomprehensible regexes instead of using a tool specifically written to handle CSV files?

Comment: Edited! When I run ./script.sh ./headlines_words.csv in Ubuntu the terminal doesn't give me any row when actually the row 8964;52224;2010;USA;witchcraft;0;1912;0.0;10;935;935;female stereotypes exists and sets the three conditions.

Comment: @knittl because it is the statement of a subject of Master Degree, I didn't choose that way.

Comment: With grep -P (PCRE): `grep -P '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];(?!=all countries).*' file`

Comment: Whomever set the assignment doesn't know much about IT. Bash/grep is not a good choice here. Instead, a sensible choice would be to use python, the Lingua Franca of the data science world, to parse the file using a CSV parsing library and query it. Rust is also popular amoung data scientists. Anything but bash/grep

Comment: @Bohemian, there are clean and sane ways to write this with bash (particularly if one takes an expansive view and treats awk -- itself a general-purpose scripting language designed with particular focus on text processing -- as in scope). What makes the assignment utterly insane is the requirement that it be solved via exactly one call to `grep -E`.

Comment: @Uri, it's inaccurate to say that EREs are not part of bash. `grep` is not part of bash, but grep is not the only way to evaluate EREs, and `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` is another ERE evaluation mechanism that _is_ part of bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, this seems more like a code golf puzzle.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okey!!! I will deep my study about EREs then. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SInce this your project requirement to use `grep -E`, here is a `grep` solution:

```bash
grep -E '^([^;]*;){2}201[01];([^a]|a[^l]|al[^l]|all[^ ]|all [^c]|all c[^o]|all co[^u]|all cou[^n]|all coun[^t]|all count[^r]]|all countr[^i]]|all countri[^e]|all countrie[^s])([^;]*;){6}(9[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,});' file

8964;52224;2010;USA;witchcraft;0;1912;0.0;10;935;935;female stereotypes
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YLf2Zc/1)

However I must add that `awk` is far more suitable tool for this job and an awk solution would be this:

```bash
awk -F ';' '
 NR == 1 || ($3 ~ /^201[01]$/ && $4 != "all countries" && $10 >= 910)
' file

Unnamed: 0;Unnamed: 0.1;year;country;word;frequency;count;freq_prop_headlines;word_len;freq_rank;hfreq_rank;theme
8964;52224;2010;USA;witchcraft;0;1912;0.0;10;935;931;female stereotypes
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you again! I know awk should be suitable, but the professor put us the grep -E use as mandatory :(